# Checking that if a value in a column is true, then all values to the left are also true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
|    0 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Taking a look at the sample table above, the goal is to check for cases when a value in a column is true, but one or more columns to the left of it in the same row are not true.

I've done this with a messy nested if statement, starting with `ColE`, checking if it is true, then checking if `ColA` through `ColD` are also true, then going to `ColD` and doing the same thing, until I've checked every column (`ColA` doesn't need to be checked because there are no columns to the left of it).

So, for example, that logic will flag the second and third rows as errors, because a column to the right of a false column is true, but the first row is okay.

Is there a way to simplify this logic or is this as elegant as it gets?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: `df.eq(0,axis=1).sum(axis=1)` ?

Comment: @Mykola Zotko A simple true/false flag for each row indicating whether or not such an error was found.

Comment: To clarify, in your example `[0,1,1,1,1]` is bad, but `[1,1,1,1,0]` or `[1,0,0,0,0]` would be okay?

Comment: @G.Anderson Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with `axis=1`
to detect the changes of values ​​by rows, then with [`DataFrame.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) we set to `1` in those places where the change is from `0` to `1`:

```
df['flag']=df.shift(axis=1,fill_value=1).lt(df).any(axis=1)
```

**Output df**

```
   ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD  ColE   flag
0     1     1     1     1     1  False
1     1     1     0     1     0   True
2     0     1     1     1     1   True
```

if you want 0 or 1 use `.view('uint8')` at the end.

**Detail**

```
print(df.shift(axis=1,fill_value=1).lt(df))
    ColA   ColB   ColC   ColD   ColE   
0  False  False  False  False  False  
1  False  False  False   True  False  
2  False   True  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df.shift(-1, axis=1).le(df).iloc[:,:-2].all(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

In the first step we shift all values to the left:

```
df.shift(-1, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD  ColE
0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   NaN
1   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   NaN
2   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   NaN
```

In the second step we compare if shifted values are less than or equal to original values:

```
df.shift(-1, axis=1).le(df)
```

Output:

```
    ColA  ColB   ColC  ColD   ColE
0   True  True   True  True  False
1   True  True  False  True  False
2  False  True   True  True  False
```

In the last step we ignore the last column and check if all values in each row are `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
df.diff(axis=1).gt(0).any(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD  ColE   Flag
0     1     1     1     1     1  False
1     1     1     0     1     0   True
2     0     1     1     1     1   True
```

---

#### Expanded Testing

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3:1, 4:1},
 'ColB': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3:1, 4:0},
 'ColC': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3:1, 4:0},
 'ColD': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3:1, 4:0},
 'ColE': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3:0, 4:0},
 'Flag': {0: False, 1: True, 2: True}})

df['Flag'] = df.diff(axis=1).gt(0).any(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD  ColE   Flag
0     1     1     1     1     1  False
1     1     1     0     1     0   True
2     0     1     1     1     1   True
3     1     1     1     1     0  False
4     1     0     0     0     0  False
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Comment: @MykolaZotko Thanks.